# Finding subclass member in a list of superclass. C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Say I have the following structure(Incomplete code)

```
public class Person{}
public class Adult : Person{
    bool hasCar;
}
public class Child : Person{
    bool goesToSchool;
}
```

And I have a list of Person:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>;
```

and the list is populated with adults and children.

Lets say I want to find the first adult where hasCar is true.

I tried:

```
Adult carOwner = people.Find((Adult x) => x.hasCar);
```

Trying this, I get an error:

"Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'Predicate< Person>' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types.  Parameter 1 is declared as type 'Adult' but should be 'Person'."

I would have thought because Adult is a subclass of Person, that the conversion should be valid.  What should I do to make my code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Linq expression that uses extension methods [Enumerable.OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 var adultWithCar = people.OfType<Adult>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.hasCar);
```